# What is net dipole moment of a spherically symmetric charge distribution?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, dipole-moment

There is some unknown spherically symmetric charge distribution $\rho(r)$ with total charge zero. For this charge distribution how will be monopole and dipole moment? Will they be zero or non zero?

 As net charge is zero the monopole term is clearly zero. But I can't imagine what will be the dipole. I think as it is spherically symmetric and net charge is also zero so dipole moment should be zero. But I am not sure about it.

 Please clear my doubt if possible.

Comment: i think it would depend on the charge distribution of all the positive charges and negative charges

Comment: I'd assume spherically symmetric means that both the center of the negative as well as the center of the positive charges are at r=0. Since the dipole would be the vector connecting them, I think it should be zero.